# Solr 4.8.1 DataImporter intermittently fails with no exception

Tags: java, solr

I have a dataimporter running nightly, and it will fail for one or more entities intermittently.  I've scoured my logs and there was no indication of why it failed.  I decided to remotely debug the DataImporter.java class to see if I could get more information.  Please refer to this link for the line number references:

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.solr/solr-dataimporthandler/4.8.1/org/apache/solr/handler/dataimport/DataImporter.java

In the doFullImport method on line 402, the indexing is kicked off.  There is a success flag that is used to determine whether or not a rollback should occur on line 419.  When my indexing fails, this line is always hit, BUT the exception on line 416 is never caught.  I'm not exactly sure how that would be the case, because if no exception is thrown I would expect the success flag to be set to true on line 414.  Since no exception is thrown, there is nothing logged.  Please let me know if you have any insight on either causes of the errors or ways to get solr to log more information about rollbacks.

Comment: Did you enable all "level" logs?

Comment: I did, but with no luck.  I eventually found the problem, which I posted as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was an out of memory exception being thrown.  Since this version of the DataImporter catches Exception instead of Throwable, it was not being logged.  I eventually found the problem by connecting a remote debugger and breaking on any exceptions from within this class.